# Unsupported OS Device Support Files update

Tags: ios, xcode

So I was running iOS 16.7 beta on my 13 pro max and I was getting the unsupported os device in my Xcode 13.2 on my MacBook 2014 running Big Sur . I wanted to know when there will be an update so that I could use my iPhone as a real device in Xcode and how often are the archives updated since I've also seen that there is an iOS 17 beta . or if there was a work around or a way that I could use my device to help me run code

I looked up support files for iOS devices and all that I seen was support for 16.5 and below , not 16.7 or 17

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, here https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport you can find up to 16.6 but in the readme there's a solution for iOS 17.

Also we should be able to extract the folder from the latest Xcode as seen [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/10iyr2r/comment/j5hzk3h/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Update:

I downloaded 16.6, renamed the folder to 16.7, placed the folder on `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
and restarted xCode and it works now.

Should be good while they update the repos with the latest support folder.